# Having problem with retrieving a document from the files collection with gridfs bucket via the id property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to retrieve a document from the file collection by the id property but it returns zero document. I am 100% the document exist in the database and that I use id that is used in a document.

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

    constructor(@Inject(MONGODB_GRIDFS) private gridFs: GridFSBucket) {}

    private async throwOnError(id: ObjectID): Promise<void> {
        const cursor = this.gridFs.find({ _id: id }).limit(1);

        const documents = await cursor.toArray();

        if (documents.length === 0) throw new HttpException("Image not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.gridFs` ?

Comment: And what documentation are you following.

Comment: I am using bare bone mongodb with node js. The gridfs api is used for storing files in mongodb in standard way. Here is a link to the documentation https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/GridFSBucket.html

Comment: Also this.gridfs is a instance of GridFSBucket class. It is automatically injected by the framework i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake i tried to access the gridfs documents from a collection that didn't exist.